# Upload not working correctly, won't give correct message / file is too big / wrong document type

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, upload, controls

My upload form displays both error messages and still doesn't seem to be working even if my documents are 36kb and it says they are more than 100000. What's going on? I'm testing from a web form and when putting the control on the server it's simply not outputting the updated error messages, but the old ones. Also it's not once uploaded correctly to the file structure (inside the same folder from the looks of things)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;


namespace FileUpload
{
    //this backend for the web control will be used to upload a file that will have it's XML tags pulled and displayed on a page. 
    //this code checks if the fileupload control has input inside it, then proceeds to the next page with the document saved.
    public partial class UploadFileControl : System.Web.UI.UserControl
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
        //names the script manager which will be used when the user attempts to upload a form / gives an error if they incorrectly attempt to upload
        protected void UploadButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //if file is located
            if (FileUploadControl.HasFile)
            {
                try
                {
                    //allow content type of document / docx
                    if (FileUploadControl.PostedFile.ContentType == "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document")
                    {
                        //if the file is is less than 51mb
                        if (FileUploadControl.PostedFile.ContentLength < 10000)
                        {
                            //name the filename, find the path of the name
                            string filename = Path.GetFileName(FileUploadControl.FileName);
                            //path of server upload (we just need to save it as a variable to be found on the next page, as it will be made / deleted
                            FileUploadControl.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/") + filename);
                            //update the label with file uploaded
                            StatusLabel.Text = "Upload status: File uploaded!";

                            //move onto template wizard page
                            Response.Redirect("http://portal.acoura.com/admin/templatewizard.aspx", false);

                            //will be used to grab the document string
                            return;

                        }
                        else
                            //display the size the file needs to be less than
                            StatusLabel.Text = "Upload status: The file has to be less than 10mb!";
                    }
                    else
                        //tell the user only docx files are accepted
                        StatusLabel.Text = "Upload status: Only DOCX files are accepted!";
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    //display the exception message, in which case it would be either size / type / if it's present
                    StatusLabel.Text = "Upload status: The file could not be uploaded. The following error occured: " + ex.Message;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure about that ContentLength line? maybe if you change this

```
if (FileUploadControl.PostedFile.ContentLength < 10000)
```

to this

```
if (FileUploadControl.PostedFile.ContentLength < 10485760) // 10mb
```

the code will run successfully

Comment: Cheers. I made a similar post yday and no one picked up on it either, I wasn't sure on how to format this. It now succesfully redirects and uploads the file to the directory!